# Fetching rows in array using SELECT * FROM table WHERE IN

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am trying to fetch data from a particular coloumn from all rows.

Eg Situation:
DB Data: id, fbid, name

```
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM table WHERE table.fbid IN (1234,5678,4321)';
$sql_run = mysql_query($sql); 
$sql_fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_run);
print_r($sql_fetch);
```

This returns the data when I test it using Sequel PRO or PHPmyAdmin.
But when I print the array it only displays one value.

Can you help me with a solution or tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Plus the usual caveats about deprecated methods.

Comment: You should loop it through a while, or for or get rid of mysql_* as @Strawberry mentioned and use PDO::fetchAll();

Comment: The two concepts (getting rid of mysql_ and using a loop) are not mutually exclusive!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];
  echo "<br>";
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: +1 for using `mysqli_*` instead. It might be worth adding a warning that `mysql_*` methods are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Before using a function, or - at least - when it does not what you expect - it's always a good idea to read the function description in the manual page.

PHP provides extremely easy access to its manual pages. All you need to type in the address bar is php.net/function name. It takes less time than typing whole question on Stack Overflow, yet you will get **exactly the same answer.** Think of efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through each row

```
$sql_run = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while ($sql_fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_run)) {
  print_r($sql_fetch);
}
```